# Despite having created a specific SSL certificate for a GKE ingress, I still cannot reach the IP address with HTTPS

Tags: load-balancing, https, kubernetes

I created an ingress for a GKE cluster providing a SSL certificate. Now that ingress presents two IP adresses, one with HTTP with a port :80 and another one with HTTPS with a port 443. The problem is that when visiting the HTTPS one, it still shows NOT SECURE. I created this diagram in order to explain my architecture. Many many thanks for any advice.
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1JLTlIFwwxNN7NK66dxM6rqhIOUQukVuFvMTRx7UGPK4/edit

Here the YAML

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s-be-XXXXX--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX":"HEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s-fw-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s-fws-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s-tps-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: k8s-ssl-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ingress.kubernetes.io/static-ip: k8s-fw-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s-tp-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  creationTimestamp: "2020-10-14T05:58:37Z"
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer
  generation: 1
  name: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress
  namespace: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  resourceVersion: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ingresses/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ingress
  uid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-service
    servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - secretName: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-certificate
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: 1.You use gke ingress or another one, like [kubernetes nginx ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)? 2.What you mean by `Now that ingress presents two IP adresses`? 3.Have you followed any [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) for ssl certificates?? 4.Could you add your ingress yaml?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
1. I am using GKE ingress.
2. If I go inside my load balancer HTTPs details, it shows 2 frontend protocols: the first one has HTTPS with port 443 and a certificate, the second one has HTTP port 80 and no certificate.
3. Yes that page, I created a Self-managed certificates shared with Google Cloud using OpenSSL.
4. I am adding the YAML as answer below

Comment: Inspect the certificate in your browser. It tell you exactly why it is not secure.

Comment: Could you please check and tell me what is the message if you use `curl -vvI https://ip`? If you enter this ip with a chrome browser do you get `Your connection is not private - Back to Safety`?

Comment: I managed to create a ManagedCertificate as well as an ingress using CLI. Despite having a load balancer with protocol HTTPS, my website is reachable only with HTTP. If i run ``` curl -vvI https://ip``` I obtain:
``` 
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: Ok It finally worked, I had to wait a few minutes before having finally the HTTPS. THis is the tutorial I followed skipping the point number 2 (Create a NodePort Service), 
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#gcloud

Comment: Many many thanks Jakub and Gerald!

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community answer with summary of our comments for better visibility.

### Issue

Https didn't work on gke with gke ingress.

### Solution

The answer here would be to just wait, as it may take up to few minutes for the load balancer to work properly.

As mentioned by @robimalco

> I had to wait a few minutes before having finally the HTTPS. This is the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#gcloud) I followed

That's also pointed in point 3 of above tutorial.

> Note: It may take up to 10-20 minutes for the load balancer to begin functioning.